# PHP foreach acting strange

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array called `$blocks` that `print_r()` function on it will result:

```
Array ( [0] => template.header [1] => error [2] => emails.addEmail )
```

and here is my code is:

```
if(count($blocks)) {
    foreach ($blocks as $block) {
        echo $block;
        $parts = explode('.', $block);
        if (count($parts) > 1) {
            list($folder, $file) = $parts;
            $folder = $folder . '/';
            echo BASE . '/blocks/' . $folder . $file . '.php';
        } else {
            echo BASE . '/blocks/' . $file . '.php';
        }
    }
    $parts = null;
}
```

but it's acting strangely and `echo` on line 3 gives me this:

```
template.header
error
error
```

The third one must be `emails.addEmail` but it's duplicating the second one.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

**Update:** I removed `@` and replaced it with `if (count($parts) > 1)`. Sorry about that guys. But it doesn't have anything to do with my problem! Still need help...

**Update 2:** I was using `$block` variable somewhere before this code and it was connected by reference to another thing. The problem got fixed by changing that variable name. Thanks you guys for your help.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `include` statements?

Comment: @Jack test it .. it works fine without include ... see : http://codepad.viper-7.com/sRIxMT

Comment: @Jack wow! i changed include to echo and now it's showing `/var/www/newsletter/blocks/template/header.php` 3 times!

Comment: Please use array_key_exists or isset instead of error suppression "@" operator. Really bad practice.

Comment: @WayneC Thanks, but it has nothing to do with my problem!

Comment: `header.php` does contain something using `$blocks` doesn't it? Try to put this piece of code inside a scope (a function for example) and try it.

Comment: The provided code works perfectly fine when put into a file on it's own. All answers provided without complete code are going to be purely speculation. The **scope** at which you include a file (I am assuming inclusion based on the comments) means that re-use of any variables used within the foreach. Remember the foreach will make a copy of the array, so modifying `$blocks` will not actually do anything.

Comment: @Leigh Take a look at `update 2`. the echo parts are include in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impression was that some (included) file is somehow manipulating either the `$blocks` array or `$block` itself. You should avoid referencing variables that way; keep variable changes close to the scope where they're being used.

Other issues I found:

```
echo BASE . '/blocks/' . $file . '.php';
```

Should be:

```
echo BASE . '/blocks/' . $block . '.php';
```

Because `$file` only gets set if `$parts` contains at least two elements.

Also to test if the split has `explode()` returned two items:

```
if (isset($parts[1])) { ... }
```

Or:

```
if (count($parts) > 1) { ... }
```

Working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6oNhBv

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'You should avoid changing global variables that way.'?

Comment: @faridv Have you looked inside those included files and see what they're doing?

Comment: They are empty at this time! I mean they are containing bunch of HTML code, not a single line of PHP.

Comment: I found it. Your first answer was right. I was using $block somewhere before by reference. That was the problem. edit your answer to you first one so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @faridv See my code pastie in the updated answer; it works fine there, so perhaps you could see what's different in your own code and fix it accordingly?